# BrainJS ReferenceError: brain is not defined

Tags: javascript, brain.js

I'm following a tutorial on how to work with neural networks with brain.js when I try to run the code it gives me a ReferenceError: brain is not defined i already installed via npm and have the CDN on the HTML.

```
const net = new brain.NeuralNetwork({ hiddenLayers: [3] });

const trainingData = [
  { input: [0, 0], output: [0] },
  { input: [0, 1], output: [1] },
  { input: [1, 0], output: [1] },
  { input: [1, 1], output: [0] }
];

net.train(trainingData);

console.log(net.run([0, 0]));
```

here´s the index.html

`````
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="//unpkg.com/brain.js"></script>

    <script src="index.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
````
`````

Comment: Can you ensure that you are loading the brain.js library before your own scripts?

Comment: yeah, I just uploaded the index :)

Comment: you either install from npm and import (with the help of module bundlers) or use cdn not both.

Comment: thanks, ill try using require

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the explicit protocol `https://` rather than just using `//`. When I do this, your code works for me.

```js
const net = new brain.NeuralNetwork({ hiddenLayers: [3] });

const trainingData = [
  { input: [0, 0], output: [0] },
  { input: [0, 1], output: [1] },
  { input: [1, 0], output: [1] },
  { input: [1, 1], output: [0] }
];

net.train(trainingData);

console.log(net.run([0, 0]));
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/brain.js"></script>

    <script src="index.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `````<script src="https://unpkg.com/brain.js"></script>`````i did it like this, the problem persists

Comment: I am using the exact code in your question, except for this change, and this works.

Comment: yeah, I don't know what could be the problem. ````(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { const net = new brain.NeuralNetwork({ hiddenLayers: [3] });````this is what terminal shows me on top of the reference error. maybe I need to install another dependency?

Comment: No, I did not need to add any dependencies to get your code working. It's more likely some weird/silly error. Something like: you're saving the wrong file, or another dependency is interfering with this.

Comment: I've added the snippet of your exact code with nothing but the protocol added. You can witness, from here, that it works.